# ServerName no longer works as SQL Server 2008 Default instance name?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Folks,
Somehow in struggling to install something (Sage MIP), I have unsettled my system's SQL Server 2008 instance names.

If I fired up SSMS and connected to "MySystemName" (while logged into MySystemName), I used to immediately connect and could view my databases.  Now if I connect to "(local)" or "." I connect just fine...but "MySystemName" gives me a timeout error.

If I log in with "." and do "SELECT @@SERVERNAME" it comes back with "MySystemName" just fine.

I've double checked that my network name is in the Security\Logins list, and it is, as a dbadmin.

Any suggestions?  I thought that having SQL Server 2005 Express might be a problem (the "battle of the default instances"), so I uninstalled that.  No better.

Comment: SELECT @@SERVERNAME doesn't gives under all circumstances the correct 'real' servername, please see micorosft's bol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the SQL Server logs? When SQL Server startsup, it logs things like the servername, IP address, and port number that it is listening on. Have you tried pinging the old SQL Server name? Does it respond?

I've seen something similar before when a SQL Server was cloned (P2V), and the new VM was given a different server name - the SQL Server got a little confused about job histories and other stuff.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the best answer...but I'm still a little puzzled.  I did look at the startup logs, and found that it was connecting to my instance using 127.0.0.1.  I had found that "." worked, and "(local)" worked, and so tried 127.0.0.1 and that also worked.  On a lark I went back to trying my instance name, and BAM, it's working again.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Setup sets the servername during installation to your computername. To change the name of the server use sp_addserver and restart the server.

Comment: I didn't want to rename it - I wanted it to "use" the name it apparently already has.  When I do SELECT @@SERVERNAME I got the name that I thought it should have - but connections to that name would time out.